# Error while doing a lexicographical sort of a word

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

I get the following error while trying to do a lexicographical sort of string

> ERROR Message :"Count cannot be less than zero. Parameter name: count"

```
 List<string> words = new List<string>();
        words.Add("collin");

        foreach (var word in words)
        {
            IEnumerable<string> sortedSubstrings =
                           Enumerable.Range(0, word.Trim().Length)
                               .Select(i => word.Substring(i))
                               .OrderBy(s => s.Length < 1 ? s : s.Remove(1, Math.Min(s.Length - 3, 3)));

        }
```

I am trying to enhance this sort by skipping the 2nd,3rd and 4th character during the lexicographical sort process

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making your .OrderBy line handle lengths less then 3 and make them 0. That's where your exception is from.

```
.OrderBy(s => s.Length < 1 ? s : s.Remove(1, Math.Min(Math.Max(0,s.Length - 3), 3)));
```